# prefetch data with header and body next.js

Tags: next.js, prefetch, getstaticprops

I have question about prefetching data.

As i know, normally we can not prefetch data with header and body in getstaticprops nextjs 12 or new fetch way in nextjs 13 because it rendered on the server and we send header and body from client.

I searched a lot, but could not find anything useful, is there any way to do that or we should skip that?